# Game of Life in D Programming Language

Tags: arrays, d

I am trying to implement the Game of Life in D (it's new to me).  It works well for arrays of sizes 100x100, 200x200, 300x300 but when I get to 400x400 and higher, the executable file stops working.  How do I fix this?  Here's my code:

```d
import std.stdio;
import std.random;
import std.conv:to;
import std.file;
import std.conv:to;
import core.simd;

alias  to!(string) toString;

immutable side = 400;
immutable generations = 1000;

alias  to!(string) toString;

void main ()
{

//Initialize Game of Life

float[side+2][side+2] big_grid;
float[side][side] cell_grid;

//Input random numbers in the big grid

for ( int i = 1; i < side+1; i++ )
    for ( int k = 1; k < side+1; k++ )
    {
    big_grid[i][k] = uniform(0,2);
    }

//Wrap the cells to sides (toroidal) in the big grid

for (int k = 1; k < side+1; k++ )
    {
    big_grid[side+1][k] = big_grid[1][k];
    big_grid[0][k] = big_grid[side][k];
    big_grid[k][side + 1] = big_grid[k][1];
    big_grid[k][0] = big_grid[k][side];
    }

big_grid[side+1][side+1] = big_grid[1][1];
big_grid[0][0] = big_grid[side][side];
big_grid[0][side+1] = big_grid[side][1];
big_grid[side+1][0] = big_grid[1][side];

//Transfer cell information from big grid to cell grid

for ( int i = 1; i < side+1; i++ )
    for ( int k = 1; k < side+1; k++ )
    {
    cell_grid[i-1][k-1] = big_grid[i][k];
    }

File file = File("gen0.txt", "w");
for ( int i = 0; i < side; i++ )
    {
        for ( int k = 0; k < side; k++ )
        {
        file.write(cell_grid[i][k],",");
        }
        file.write("\n");
    }
file.close();

//Update the state of the cells

for (int d = 1; d < generations; d++ )
    {

    //Rules of Life

    for ( int i = 0; i < side; i++ )
        for ( int k = 0; k < side; k++ )
        {
        if (big_grid[i+1][k+1] == 0 && (big_grid[i][k]+big_grid[i][k+1]+big_grid[i][k+2]+big_grid[i+1][k]+big_grid[i+1][k+1]+big_grid[i+1][k+2]+big_grid[i+2][k]+big_grid[i+2][k+1]+big_grid[i+2][k+2] == 3))
            {
            cell_grid[i][k] = 1;
            }
        else if (big_grid[i+1][k+1] == 1 && ((big_grid[i][k]+big_grid[i][k+1]+big_grid[i][k+2]+big_grid[i+1][k]+big_grid[i+1][k+1]+big_grid[i+1][k+2]+big_grid[i+2][k]+big_grid[i+2][k+1]+big_grid[i+2][k+2] == 3) || (big_grid[i][k]+big_grid[i][k+1]+big_grid[i][k+2]+big_grid[i+1][k]+big_grid[i+1][k+1]+big_grid[i+1][k+2]+big_grid[i+2][k]+big_grid[i+2][k+1]+big_grid[i+2][k+2] == 4)))
            {
            cell_grid[i][k] = 1;
            }
        else
            {
            cell_grid[i][k] = 0;
            }
        }

    //Update big grid for next iteration

    for ( int i = 1; i < side+1; i++ )
        for ( int k = 1; k < side+1; k++ )
        {
        big_grid[i][k] = cell_grid[i-1][k-1];
        }

    for (int k = 1; k < side+1; k++ )
        {
        big_grid[side+1][k] = big_grid[1][k];
        big_grid[0][k] = big_grid[side][k];
        big_grid[k][side + 1] = big_grid[k][1];
        big_grid[k][0] = big_grid[k][side];
        }

    big_grid[side+1][side+1] = big_grid[1][1];
    big_grid[0][0] = big_grid[side][side];
    big_grid[0][side+1] = big_grid[side][1];
    big_grid[side+1][0] = big_grid[1][side];

    file = File("gen"~toString(d)~".txt", "w");
    for ( int i = 0; i < side; i++ )
    {
        for ( int k = 0; k < side; k++ )
        {
        file.write(cell_grid[i][k],",");
        }
        file.write("\n");
    }
    file.close();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most likely cause is the default stack limit using Windows, and there are at least two paths to work around it.

#### 1. Increase stack limit.

If you compile and run programs on Windows, executable files usually have their own maximum stack size compiled in, so it's more of an OS specific than a language specific.

Now, for compiled programming languages, their linkers usually provide options to increase the maximum stack size. For example, if you use dmd (the official D compiler) and compile to 32-bit target, the command line would be `dmd -L/STACK:16777216 program.d` to set the limit to 16 mebibytes. The list of dmd linker's options is [here](http://www.digitalmars.com/ctg/ctgLinkSwitches.html).

#### 2. Avoid massive stack usage.

Another path is to note that you need the stack only for local plain-old-data variables. The array `float[side+2][side+2] big_grid;` is a *static* array, meaning that it is allocated where it is declared as `(side+2)` * `(side+2)` consecutive 4-byte `float`s.

If you instead use a *dynamic* array `auto big_grid = new float [] [] (side + 2, side + 2);`, this will allocate only `size_t` * 2 bytes (8 or 16 depending on the bit-ness) on the stack, and the rest of the allocations (one one-dimensional array of dynamic arrays of floats, and `size+2` one-dimensional arrays of floats) will happen on the garbage-collected heap. You can read more about different kinds of [arrays in D](http://dlang.org/spec/arrays.html), and even more on using [dynamic arrays](http://dlang.org/d-array-article.html).

You can also declare the array as *thread-local*: just move the declaration from function scope to module scope. If you want a real global variable, prepend `__gshared` to the module-level declaration: `__gshared float[side+2][side+2] big_grid;`. This way, you can still use a static array while not allocating on the stack.